# Can I Zoom with Highcharts using a datatable with switchRowsAndColumns

Tags: highcharts, zooming

UPDATE 2: I'm back to seeing a different results, depending on the setting of the switchRowsAndColumns value.

FWIW: I have also tried to use the xAxis: { minRange:1}, to see if that helps. No luck.

UPDATE 1: The problem seems to be if the X-point values are numeric, life is good. But if they are alpha, then no good.

I can get zooming to work if I have a chart that gets it's data from and HTML table AS LONG AS the switchRowsAndColumns is set to false. If switchRowsAndColumns is set to true, the chart reflects the change correctly BUT zooming doesn't seem to work. Am I missing a setting?

OK, Here is the code I am using and I want to make a correction to my question. It seems now that the zooming doesn't work ('x', 'y', or 'xy') regardless of the switchRowsAndColumns value (true or false)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
// Parse the data from an inline table using the Highcharts Data plugin
Highcharts.chart('container', {
data: {
table: 'datatable',
switchRowsAndColumns: false
},
chart: {
type: 'column',
zoomType: 'x'
},
title: {
text: 'myTitle',
x: -1
},
legend: {
layout: 'vertical',
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'middle',
borderWidth: 0
}
});
});    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 420px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div >
<table id="datatable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Col1</th>
<th>Col2</th>
<th>Col3</th>
<th>Col4</th>
<th>Col5</th>
<th>Col6</th>
<th>Col7</th>
<th>Col8</th>
<th>Col9</th>
<th>Col10</th>
<th>Col11</th>
<th>Col12</th>
<th>Col13</th>
<th>Col14</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Row1</td>
<td>91</td>
<td>84</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>93</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>93</td>
<td>96</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>93</td>
<td>85</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row2</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>87.5</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>98</td>
<td>95</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>75</td>
<td>92</td>
<td>75</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row3</td>
<td>75</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>83</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>95</td>
<td>95</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>92.5</td>
<td>93</td>
<td>85</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row4</td>
<td>87.5</td>
<td>95</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>91</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>76</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>92.5</td>
<td>89</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>83</td>
<td>88</td>
<td>75</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row5</td>
<td>75</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>93.75</td>
<td>83</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>75</td>
<td>86</td>
<td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row6</td>
<td>95</td>
<td>87.5</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>91</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>89</td>
<td>75</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>95</td>
<td>90</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>91</td>
<td>88</td>
<td>78</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We do not know if you are missing a setting as you have not provided any code.

Comment: On the fiddle it seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/Lsmanjj6/

Comment: Actually, when I go to your jsfiddle, the zoom works the same way as mine. It looks like it tries to zoom, but the result is wrong.

FWIW, I'm using chrome.

Comment: moganfree, I get your jsfiddle to work 'IF' I change the name of the X-Points from 'Jane' and 'John' to '1' and '2'